# Duplicates of a .swift file are shown in terminal from git when running the command git status

Tags: xcode, git, terminal

I made some changes in my project and checked the status using git status command in terminal so that I can commit changes after verifying all the files I have changed. The files changed are all fine but, it shows some duplicates of one file. lets say the file's name is xyz.swift. It shows output like:

```
On branch MyBranch
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

root/Subroot/Core/xyz.swift 10.swift
root/Subroot/Core/xyz.swift 11.swift
root/Subroot/Core/xyz.swift 12.swift
root/Subroot/Core/xyz.swift 13.swift
root/Subroot/Core/xyz.swift 14.swift
root/Subroot/Core/xyz.swift 15.swift
root/Subroot/Core/xyz.swift 16.swift
root/Subroot/Core/xyz.swift 17.swift
root/Subroot/Core/xyz.swift 5.swift
root/Subroot/Core/xyz.swift 6.swift
root/Subroot/Core/xyz.swift 7.swift
root/Subroot/Core/xyz.swift 8.swift
root/Subroot/Core/xyz.swift 9.swift

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Can someone please help me out with this. this duplication keeps increasing in numbers. First it was 4 or 5 files. now it show more than 25 files like that. if I use git add -u these files do not get added. but if i do git add ., it creates duplicates and adds to project. Also, in my XCode project there is only one xyz.swift is visible. But, somehow, in terminal it shows these weird duplicates.

Your help is really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.... Happy coding.

Comment: Have you copied your files from some where ? In mac when you copy files over you will end up with duplicates if the file names are same. Xcode won't recognize them until you add it to the project.

Comment: No  @GoodSp33d, I have cloned the project from remote repository.

Answer (score 0):

Look in your target's build phases within Xcode for a busted "Copy Files" build phase.

It might look something like this:

[image: Copy Files Build Phase]

My guess is that Xcode is copying the Swift file into the same place again and again and instead of deleting the previous file, Xcode helpfully adds another copy.  Either way, make sure you don't have a Copy Files build phase that shouldn't be there.